# Is using classmethod on django models instead of manager a good practice?

Tags: django, model

I'm currently using Django 1.6

I'm wondering whether using class method instead of manager on a Model Class is a good idea.

---

**For example:**

Now suppose I have an `Option Model` as below:

```
class Option(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    value = models.TextField()
```

And the options are regard to be some `key - value - pairs` in my db table.

Ordinary, if I want to read a option, I may execute:

```
Option.objects.get('key').value()
```

And this statement may raise exception, now I want to write a `get` method which will return `None` automatically on exception.

As I know, if I want to set a method on the class, with django manner, we might define our own manager, most probably like the below:

```
Option.my_manager.get('key')  # returns the option value or None
```

But here I may have another choice: **classmethod**

```
class Option(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    value = models.TextField()

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, key):
        opt = Option.objects.filter(key=key).first()
        return opt.value if opt else None
```

This works, and we can call it with a more pretty way:

```
Option.get('key')
```

So I want to ask, in the general way, would using classmethod be a good practice in django?

And if it do, why should we use manager?

Comment: I don't think this is doing the same thing as a manager. A manager typically alters the behaviour of `filter` rather than `get`.

Comment: @cms_mgr You see, in fact using class method, I can also return a `queryset` but not only a `value`, then cascading filter calls.